# Instantiating a dynamic array after erase

Tags: vba, dynamic-arrays, visio

I am trying to instantiate a dynamic array after erasing it.
I use an array to store shapes that I create so that I dont need to loop every shape on the page. Since there are many already. Every new page I erase the array but then run into a "subscript out of range" error when I try to add the first shape to the array.

```
Dim SeqShapes() As Shape
For PageCount = 0 to activeDocument.Pages.Count
    Erase SeqShapes

    For ShapesNeeded = 0 to ShapesCount
        Set NewShape = ActivePage.Drop(SomeShape, 20, 20)
        SeqShapes(UBound(SeqShapes)) = NewShape
    Next

    'Some more code

Next
```

This returns an error because there are no entries in the array.
I don't want to use a fixed array because there is no way to know how many shapes will be created beforehand.

I have tried adding a dummy record but can't seem to figure out the syntax:

```
Dim SeqShapes() As Shape
Dim DummyShape As Shape
For PageCount = 0 to activeDocument.Pages.Count
    Erase SeqShapes
    SeqShapes(0) = DummyShape

    For ShapesNeeded = 0 to ShapesCount
        Set NewShape = ActivePage.Drop(SomeShape, 20, 20)
        SeqShapes(UBound(SeqShapes)) = NewShape
    Next

    'Some more code

Next
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have a 1 dimensional array, you can use `ReDim Preserve arrname(LBound(arrname) To UBound(arrname) + 1)` for example, to keep the previous values and increase the ubound. Thought you need to first dimension the array. I Would do `ReDim SeqShapes(1 to 1)` and then the redim preserve in every iteration. Best way is to count all the shapes beforehand and dimension the array once.

Comment: A collection or a dictionary may be of use to you also.

Comment: If you don't know the number, using `Collection` would probably be the better solution

Comment: Personally i find arrays easier to work with than collections. But using a fixed array and increasing it each iteration would solve my issue indeed. Or would learning to work with collections benefit me more in the long run?

Comment: An array is preferable when you have a fixed number of elements. A collection (or dictionary) is usually the better solution when you have a dynamic number of items. Learning about collections is for sure worth the time - and they are pretty easy to understand.

Comment: @FunThomas Thank you for your help. If you could repeat this in an answer I will gladly accept it as the solution.

Comment: Most part of objects in Visio Object model have starting index **1**, not 0 ! I also recommend that you iterate through the elements of the collection. *For each pg in ActiveDocument.Pages*, *For each shp in ActivePage.Shapes* and so on

Comment: `loop every shape on the page`, can also be done really easy with `For each shp in pg.Shapes  *  shp.doSomething  *  Next shp`, where `shp` is a declared as shape and `pg` is the page you want to run through. To run through every page you can do the same `For each pg in Document.Pages  *  --shp For Loop--  *  Next pg`

Comment: @L8n i was using this before. The reason i wanted something different is that, of the   1000 shapes only 20 are relevant to the loop. So for efficiency I didn't want to loop them all every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a collection rather than an array

```
 Dim SeqShapes As Collection
 For PageCount = 0 to activeDocument.Pages.Count
    Set SeqShapes = Nothing      '  Easiest way to clear it is to recreate it.
    Set SeqShapes = New Collection

    Dim ShapesNeeded
    Dim newShape As Shape
    For ShapesNeeded = 0 To 3
        Set newShape = ActivePage.Drop(SomeShape, 20, 20)
        SeqShapes.Add newShape     ' Add the shape into Collection
    Next ShapesNeeded  
    ...
Next PageCount
```

To loop over all shapes in the collection:

```
    ' Using ForEach (you have to declare you running variable as Variant)
    Dim sh As Variant
    For Each sh In SeqShapes
        Debug.Print sh.Name
    Next sh

    ' Using for
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To SeqShapes.Count
        Debug.Print SeqShapes(i).Name
    Next i
```